# Switch / use <dbname> in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm newbie with mongodb.

When I created the cluster it automatically created a database named < dbname > as far as I understood.

My problem now is, in the shell.
How do I switch to this database and use it?
If I try to switch to other existing dbs (use local / use admin) so it's okay.
I tried to **use < dbname > but I get an error saying < dbname > is not a valid database name**.

[Image provided - me trying to use < dbname > and getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBhZx.png)

Thank you !

Comment: use "<dbname>" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create Database From [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) GUI and use **invalid** characters:
[image]

### "The problem"

From mongodb docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Database-Names-for-Windows

**Restrictions on Database Names for Windows**

> For MongoDB deployments running on Windows, database names cannot
> contain any of the following characters:

```
/\. "$*<>:|?
```

Example:
[image]

### Solution

**Delete** this database (By compass) - and create **new** database without `<` `>`.

**Out of topic:** Better practice to use more **semantic** DB names like `Trips`, `Orders`, and so on (And not **db-name**).